# Joining two structural similar dataframes on two index columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two structural identical dataframes: column id-part1, column id-part2 and column data1.
id-part1 and id-part2 are together used as an index-

Now I want to calculate the difference between the two dataframes of column data1 with respect to the two id columns. In fact, in one data-frames it might happen that the combination of id-part1 and id-part2 is not existing...

So it is somehow a SQL join operation, ins't?

Comment: Could you please provide some data to understand it better and make a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge() function is what you are looking for.
It works similar as an SQL join operation. Given your description a solution would be:

```
solution <- merge(DF1, DF2, by = c('id-part1', 'id-part2'), all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
```

DF1 and DF2 are your corresponding data frames. merge() uses x and y to reference these data frames where x is the first (DF1) and y the second (DF2).

The **by=** property defines the column names to match (you can even specify different names for each data frame).

**all.x** and **all.y** specify the kind of join you like to perform, depending on the data you like to keep.

The result is a new data frame with different columns for data1. You can then continue with your calculations.